# Why won't any more Npcs spawn

Tags: terraria

I have 7 Npcs on terraria they all arrived fine. I want more to spawn I built a house the exact same as all the others. I waited until morning but no more spawned. Why is this happening!!

Answer (score -1):

Check the requirments for the ones you want.

Some are:

1. have a house 5x5
2. have a table/ crafting and a chair
3. have a door
4. Have a backround
5. if all of this doesn't work wait some time

but if its a specific npc look on the terraria wiki.